# Can I auto replace specific strings by returned data keys in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery.ajax to get some variables/response from the server side.

The returned data is json object like this:

```
data.consumer_key
data.consumer_secret
```

#### Question

Can I automatically replace strings found in a specific container, e.g. `div.returned_data` to replace the matching formula for the returned data automatically.

Example:

```
mystring.replace( '{{consumer_key}}', data.consumer_key  );
```

However, I want it to be dynamic. Catch all data returned and replace the `{{data_key}}` automatically. Can that be done or not? I mean, without precisely telling jquery to replace `{{consumer_key}}` but `{{replace_anything}}` with `data.replace_anything`. Hope my point is clear.

Currently this works but I need it for like 10 data keys, so I am looking for an automatic preg replace solution. any idea?

```
$( '#api-keys-options' ).html( $( '#api-keys-options' ).html().replace( '{{consumer_key}}', data.consumer_key ) );
```

Many thanks

Comment: What you're talking about is templating. This has been implemented many times already: you don't want to try doing it yourself! On a separate note, do look up the callback signature for jQuery's `html` method.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find a library called Mustache. and all I am doing now is Mustache.render( template, data ) and it works! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ajax call returns an object, lets call it `data`, and that `data` object has several properties that you want to access, you can loop over them using:

```
for (var prop in data) {
    console.log("property name: " + prop + ", property value: " + data[prop]);
}
```

In your case, you would want to replace the string `'{{' + prop +'}}'` in the value of `data[prop]` (based on the above code example).

Here is a better working snippet:

```js
data = {'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2'}
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  for (var prop in data) {
    console.log("property name: " + prop + ", property value: " + data[prop]);
    $('#d1').html(
      $('#d1').html().replace('{{'+prop+'}}', data[prop]));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">This is some text with {{name1}} variables and some {{name2}} variables</div>
<br />
<button id="btn1">Replace</button>
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, it does not use template rendering like Mustache. so i appreciate this solution and will it for my little needs.

Comment: Sometimes libraries can save you a lot of time, but sometimes it's easier to just use simple code :)

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, at least use the proper syntax for `html` (callbacks) and make sure that the value being inserted is scalar (a string or a number). You should probably also check `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @lonesomeday, can you please add a bit more information? I'm not sure I got what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: First, like the OP, you are using `html` in a very cumbersome way. You should use the [callback signature](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function). Second, you are not checking to see what kind of value you are inserting. Think what would happen if, for instance, `data.name1` was an array or an object. Third, you should never trust your data source: if you're going to use a `for .. in` loop, you should use [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check it's doing what you expect.

Comment: With some of that I agree, however when you are the one who is responsible for the data - it's not always necessary to double check everything.